# JQuery Code For Selecting Select Option & Clicking Button Not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I'm tring to select the Large size and click the button from a website. I have the html code in fiddle as well as the jquery code I tried. I've tried these (below), but it doesn't seem to be working. What did I do wrong?

This is for selecting the Large size:

```
 $('select[name="size"] option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == "Large"; }).attr("selected",true);
```

This is for clicking the button:

```
$('#add-remove-buttons').find('.button').trigger('click');
```

Here is the fiddle for what I've tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/8RnBf/645/

-Thank you

Comment: what exactly do you want it to do after you select Large size and click on button??

Comment: @HenryDev It adds the data in cart, I just need the code for clicking it..

Comment: You want to capture what was selected from medium, large, xlarge?

Comment: @Luminous_Dev I want to select the Large option through jquery

Comment: Statically you want only Large to be selected and sent? Users can not change?

Comment: @Luminous_Dev I'm trying to simulate a real click to the add to cart button, but before that I want the Large size to be automatically selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#size').val($('#size option').filter(function(ind, el) {
  return $(el).text() === 'Large';
}).val());
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rLerzj08/

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thefto_dev/8RnBf/649/)

```
 $('#add-remove-buttons').find('.button').on('click',function(e){
  alert($('select[name="size"]').val());
 });
```

I have changed only the jQuery, If this is what you wanted to capture what was selected on dropdown list when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thefto_dev/8RnBf/653/)

Make sure that the DOM is ready before this can be executed

```
$('select#size').val(39304).find('option[value="39304"]').attr('selected','selected')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#size').change(function(){

    $( "#size option:selected" ).each(function() {
       console.log( $( this ).text() );
    });

})
```